# What is the error alert dialog in Flutter? AlertDialog.adaptive

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTSBa.png)]

I have created a Dialog Widgets. It will show the Error when i write AlertDialog.adaptive. withour adaptive Widgets No erorr. Is anyone know how to fix this error.

Is anyone know how to fix this error.

Comment: Look into your editor’s error list, or hover on it.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code. Please copy paste the full code here instead of attaching partial screenshot so we can troubleshoot it properly, and copy paste the error that is showing

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10157127) also try to include flutter version ,code snippet and then you can add image imo

Comment: ''exam_view.dart'', ''chat_app_bar.dart'', error files name. https://mega.nz/file/tYAiCTIR#ubFwKv_OmODY7EjKLyhcj3vD1c1eXTGGvaC7K2yCTdY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to update your flutter version to 3.13 or higher version, because AlertDialog.adaptive feature came with 3.13.
The 3.13 framework improvement - https://medium.com/@ak187429/flutter-3-13-framework-improvements-41be37e925d8.
On the writing, the writer mentions abaout AlertDialog.adaptive.
There is example code for AlertDialog.adaptive

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: const Text('Show Alert Dialog Adaptive'),
        onPressed: () async {
          final response = await showAdaptiveDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog.adaptive(
                content: const Text('This is an adaptive alert dialog'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                    child: const Text('Cancel'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
          print(response);
        },
      ),
```

My flutter version - 3.13.8,
My dart version - 3.1.4,
This code works on my computer :)

Comment: I also use the same version ''flutter_windows_3.13.8-stable''

Comment: Here is the code file. this is very important for me. pls help me to solve this bug, my friend.  chat_app_bar.dart, exam_view.dart                                                                                              https://mega.nz/file/tYAiCTIR#ubFwKv_OmODY7EjKLyhcj3vD1c1eXTGGvaC7K2yCTdY

Answer (score 1):

I run your Code what i Did i declare a function showDialoog here is the code
and the result is in ScreenShot its working fine
[image: Result]

````dart
showDialoog(BuildContext context)async{
final endExam = await showDialog<bool>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog.adaptive(
      title: const Text("Submit Exam"),
      content: Text(
        'You have time left.\n'
        'Are you sure you want to submit?',
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, false);
          },
          child: const Text("Cancel"),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
          },
          child: const Text(
            "Submit",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
}```
````